# Django authentication and registration

Tags: django

I am trying to create the simplest website using the Django authentication and registration system on Amazon EC2. After following the Django documentation and various web tutorials I still get this error:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>       http://52.43.72.141/polls/registration/?next=/polls/2/
>
> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL
>    patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> ^polls/ ^$ [name='index']
> ^polls/ ^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
> ^polls/ ^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$ [name='results']
> ^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
> ^polls/ ^login/$ [name='login']
> ^polls/ ^ ^login/$ [name='login']
> ^polls/ ^ ^logout/$ [name='logout']
> ^polls/ ^ ^password_change/$ [name='password_change']
> ^polls/ ^ ^password_change/done/$ [name='password_change_done']
> ^polls/ ^ ^password_reset/$ [name='password_reset']
> ^polls/ ^ ^password_reset/done/$ [name='password_reset_done']
> ^polls/ ^ ^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$ [name='password_reset_confirm']
> ^polls/ ^ ^reset/done/$ [name='password_reset_complete']
> ^admin/
> ```
>
> The current URL, polls/registration/, didn't match any of these.

This is what I have in ~/w/mysite/polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Choice, Question

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    login_url = '/polls/registration/'

class ResultsView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

@login_required
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

This is what I have in ~/w/mysite/polls/registration/login.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{# Assumes you setup the password_reset view in your URLconf #}
<p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

It seems the error happens when the DetailView class is called.

Can someone help clarify how to make this work?

Comment: I have the same login.html in directories polls/templates, polls/templates/registration, polls/registration/templates and polls/registration/templates/registration

Comment: The error says that it can't find any url that matches the pattern `/polls/registration` and the list of URLs checked shows that it doesn't exist.  Did you include that URL in your urls.py file?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

What I'm seeing from your code is that you don't have /polls/registration set in your urls.py.  Im assuming you did something like:

```
url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

You need to add:

```
url('^registration/', views.WHATEVER_VIEW_YOU_WANT_USE)
```

From within your polls urls.py

Whats happening right now is when the DetailView is used, it goes to login but cant find it, as it is not in the urls.

Also side note,

From the documentation:

> The LoginRequired mixin
>
> When using class-based views, you can achieve the same behavior as with login_required by using the LoginRequiredMixin. This mixin should be at the leftmost position in the inheritance list.

So you are using both the login decorator, as well as the LoginRequired